# Android animation jumps to end

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I am trying to get a simple `ListView` expand `animation` to work. The `animation` is working but sometimes it jumps to the end then resumes the `animation`.

[GIF of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7u76.gif)

This is the code for the animation class:

```
public class DropDownAnimation extends Animation {
private int targetHeight;
private View view;
private boolean down;

public DropDownAnimation(View view, int targetHeight, boolean down) {
    this.view = view;
    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    this.down = down;
}

public DropDownAnimation(View view, int targetHeight) {
    this.view = view;
    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    this.setDuration(350);
    if(view.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        down = true;
    else
        down = false;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime,t);
    int newHeight;
    if (down) {
        newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        newHeight = (int) (targetHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    view.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
                       int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}
}
```

`Animation` is being called like this:

```
DropDownAnimation dropDownAnimation = new DropDownAnimation(toolbar,expandedHeight);
            toolbar.startAnimation(dropDownAnimation);
            View parent = (View)test.getParent();
            parent.invalidate();
```

Comment: why variables are final ,is it works with final identifier?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference but I fixed it

Comment: As a general advice, use RecyclerView with really manage animation like a god

Comment: @Maclaren Can you explain how you fixed it?